# "merge" two readers into one writer

Tags: java, io, filewriter

I need to implement the method

`void filter(Reader mails, Reader groups, Writer users) throws IOException`

in such a way that it would combine two pieces of data frow readers into one writer.

The file for `mails` would look like this:

```
Login;Email
login1;mail1@mail.com
login2;mail2@mail.com
login3;mail3@mail.com
login4;mail4@mail.com
```

and the file for `groups` would look like this:

```
Login;Group;
login1;Group1
login2;Group2
login3;Group3
login4;Group2
```

And the result of merging should look like this:

```
Login;Email;Group
login1;mail1@mail.com;Group1
login2;mail2@mail.com;Group2
login3;mail3@mail.com;Group3
login4;mail4@mail.com;Group2
```

So, what I came up with is: get a string from the first reader, then get another string from the second reader, manipulate them as needed and then write the result with writer.

But is there a way to make it differently or just more elegant?

PS: I'm obliged to use only `Reader` and `Writer` classes.

BTW: when I write something to a file with Writer and if I look into the file, I'll see something unreadable. But if I read the same file with Reader and then print it on the console, it looks ok. Is it normal? Or how can I write to the file to make it readable?

Comment: Why do you want to do this using `Reader` and `Writer`? Are the two input files always sorted so that lines from both always can be merged?

Comment: Yes, they are. Well, I don't want to use them:) but such a task)

Comment: Even if the files are sorted, one entry still could be missing. I find it hard to rely on such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement a method with this signature, you could do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String mails = "Login;Email\n"
            + "login1;mail1@mail.com\n"
            + "login2;mail2@mail.com\n"
            + "login3;mail3@mail.com\n"
            + "login4;mail4@mail.com";
    String groups = "Login;Group;\n"
            + "login1;Group1\n"
            + "login2;Group2\n"
            + "login3;Group3\n"
            + "login4;Group2";

    Reader mailsReader = new StringReader(mails);
    Reader groupsReader = new StringReader(groups);
    Writer mergedWriter = new StringWriter();

    filter(mailsReader, groupsReader, mergedWriter);

    System.out.println(mergedWriter.toString());
}

static void filter(Reader mails, Reader groups, Writer users) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader mbr = new BufferedReader(mails);
    BufferedReader gbr = new BufferedReader(groups);
    BufferedWriter ubw = new BufferedWriter(users);

    String ml = mbr.readLine();
    String gl = gbr.readLine();
    while (ml != null && gl != null) {
        ubw.write(ml + ";" + gl.split(";")[1] + "\n");
        ml = mbr.readLine();
        gl = gbr.readLine();
    }
    ubw.flush();
}
```

Output:

```
Login;Email;Group
login1;mail1@mail.com;Group1
login2;mail2@mail.com;Group2
login3;mail3@mail.com;Group3
login4;mail4@mail.com;Group2
```

Comment: This solution relies on the order of the data in the files, it could easily break.

Comment: @mike Yes. That's why I've asked in a comment: "Are the two input files always sorted so that lines from both always can be merged?" The answer was "Yes, they are."

Comment: I've also commented on that. It does not only rely on the fact that the files are sorted. **1, 2, 3** and **1, 4, 5** are a counter example.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a Map and a POJO container.

Pojo is

```
String email;
String group;
```

Then you have a hashmap

```
Map<String,EmailGroup> emailGroup = new HashMap<String,EmailGroup>();
```

Then your reading code will read the email list then populate the group after.

```
readEmail(emailGroup);
readGroup(emailGroup);


readEmail(Map<String,EmailGroup> map)
{
    EmailGroup tempgroup;
    if(map.contains(login))
    {
       tempGroup = map.get();
    }
    else
    {
       EmailGroup tempGroup = new EmailGroup();
    }
    tempGroup.setEmail(readEmailAddress);
    map.put(login,tempGroup); 
}
```

The readGroup does the same but calls setGroup();

This is not a full solution but should provide a suggestion on another possible way to resolve this issue.

Comment: I'd have a POJO `UserInfo`, but that's essentially what I was talking about. +1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Natural_join_.28.E2.8B.88.29) on the common key `Login`.
This should be easy to solve with some maps and some [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object)s.

In the following some additional information that should help clarifying my thoughts.

---

Let's consider following data table. It contains people's first and last names, their email addresses and logins.

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Login             + Email            + First name    + Last name     +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ smith             + smith@mail.com   + John          + Smith         +
+ miller            + miller@mail.com  + John          + Miller        +
+ jackson           + mail@jackson.com + Scott         + Jackson       +
+ scott             + me@scott.com     + Scott         + Jackson       +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

This information is enough for simple data inquiries. If we want to know what John Smith's email address is, we have to perform a search in the first table. If we want to know Scott Jackson's address, we have a problem, since there are two people with the exact same name in our database.

So a mean to differentiate people is necessary, that is the column `Login`. It is unique in this table and thus can be used to avoid ambiguities.
Because `Login` has this attribute, it is called **key**.

This next table contains the group affiliation per login.

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Login             + Group            +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ smith             + user             +
+ miller            + user             +
+ jackson           + admin            +
+ scott             + admin            +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Above table has `Login` as key, too. Using that property allows us to make another type of inquiry. It is possible to ask for group affiliation of persons, in order to do so, we have to retrieve the login of the user in question. Therefore the first table is used. Since `Login` is a key in the second table, it can be used to get the group affiliation.

This process is called *joining*, we combined the group affiliation from the second table, with the information on first and second names from the first table and used the login info as **key**.

A natural join performs this operation on all rows. At this point, I hope it is clear why, I proposed a join. The 2 files correspond to 2 tables (that are invariant to changes in the order of the data). Joining them results in a third table that contains all the information. Printing that table is an answer to OPs question.

To utilize the power of the underlying relational algebra a simple `java.util.Map` with `Login` as key can be used.

Comment: Yes, I could, but if one understands the concept of a join, that is superfluous. So I'd rather provide more information related to that. If it's still not clear, I'll add a small example.